# Nginx rewrite partial url

Tags: nginx, url-rewrite-module

I have the following url:

http://www.example.com/img/products/10103/f/10103-s-1.jpg

And would want to rewrite it to:

http://www.example.com/img/products/10103/10103-s-1.jpg

The numbers in between (10103) can change as can the image names. I've tried the following nginx rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^/img/products/(.+)$/f /img/products/$1 last;
```

Why does it now work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx, but that looks like a regular expression to me and `$` indicates end of line, what happens when you remove the `$` sign from the find expression?

Comment: I believe you are right. Also, I believe the last bit got cut off after the rewrite. I've changed it now to this and it works: rewrite ^/img/products/(.*)/f/(.*)$ /img/products/$1/$2 last;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current rewrite rule is matching on

```
^/img/products/(.+)$/f
```

Which means URL path starts with `/img/products/` then anything follows and the URL ends, and then `/f` follows. This can never match a single line as you're using the dollar sign which indicates a line end, and then have characters after it.

If you want to match

```
/img/products/10103/f/10103-s-1.jpg
```

You'll have to change it to `^/img/products/(.+)$`, but as you want to extract the two id-groups you're looking for `^/img/products/(.+)/f/(.+)$`, then replace it with `/img/products/$1/$2`. As you posted in the comment.